Action Invoke not working in MAUI, not null in Xamarin
I am trying to use this StackOverflow solution in my MAUI code but the action never gets invoked in the view model.
I have this declaration just as before public Action<bool> OnLoginFailed { get; set; } and I invoke that action OnLoginFailed?.Invoke(true); just as before inside a ViewModel function.
However the action never gets invoked, and when I debug through the lines, it seems like the OnLoginFailed Action appears to be null in the view model, and hence it doesn't even call the Invoke function().
Any idea why that might be the case?
I tried it in different views and view models but it's the same issue everywhere. Is there a different way to make sure it's not null?

Did you register for the action? OnLoginFailed stays null if there are no targets for the event registered.

@PMF , just like the solution showed, I did set this value in my View ViewModel.OnLoginFailed = ((obj) => {     PasswordEntry.Focus(); }); Was there anything else needed too?

If after that line, OnLoginFailed is still null, there must be something else wrong, like you're reassigning a different instance of the viewmodel or so. Please show your code.

Please help create Minimal, Reproducible Example and edit it to your post to reflect the change.
